# Error connecting to ClearDB when using Proximo

Tags: node.js, heroku, knex.js, cleardb, proximo

I'm running a Node.js app on Heroku through Proximo in order to get a static IP for outbound traffic. (See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo#using-the-proximo-http-proxy, using the `Procfile` method).

Since doing this the MySQL connection now times out and doesn't connect. I'm using Knex and connecting to ClearDB

I've tried to update the privileges to allow access to the database user from the Proximo IP like so :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEDGES ON <DB_NAME>.* TO <DB USER>@<PROXIMO IP> IDENTIFIED BY '<DB PASSWORD>'
```

But ClearDB doesnt allow this:

> Access denied for user@% to DB NAME

Is there a way I can allow access so the database connects or configure Proximo to not Proxy the MySQL connection/traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `bin/proximo` in Procfile.

```
web: bin/proximo [your existing command]
```

Proximo wraps all outbound traffics when you use proximo in Profile. If you use to require Proximo for an endpoint, you implement as bellow.

```
require "rest-client"

RestClient.proxy = ENV["PROXIMO_URL"] if ENV["PROXIMO_URL"]
res = RestClient.get("http://api.someservice.com/endpoint")
```